# Excel check formula, return specific text on error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, array

I have an excel sheet that uses an array to return the most common text found, and then the result is copied to a separate sheet so we can view the most common text per month of the year. This sheet then uses the same array to find the most common for the year. Every once in a while there is a month where there is no duplicate value, which obviously returns "#N/A". Is it possible to have excel do an error check on the array where, upon an error, instead of returning "#N/A", it returns "unreported"? Or, failing that, have the array on the second sheet ignore any errors?

**EDIT:**

```
{=INDEX(D4:D54,MODE(IF((D4:D54<>"")*ISNA(MATCH(D4:D54,$I$1:$I1,0)),MATCH(D4:D54,D4:D54,0))))}
```

Sorry about not including the formula with OP.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1349145/edit) your question to add the formula you currently have?

Comment: Replace `=[your formula]` with `=IF(ISNA([your formula]);"unreported";[your formula])` (or use additional column if you do not want to repeat the formula twice).

Comment: Please provide a sample about your problem.

Comment: Better you include the Formula with OP will help us to fix it.

Comment: Sorry guys, formula added with edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the whole formula in `IFERROR`:

```
=IFERROR([your formula],"unreported").
```

This will return the result of your formula if it is not an error and will return "unreported" if it is an error.